# Can I persuade Make to give me a better error message when prerequisites are given through a variable with secondary expansion?

Tags: gnu-make

Observe:

```
OBJECT_FILES=

.PHONY: all
all: project.exe

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.exe:: $$(OBJECT_FILES);

project.exe: OBJECT_FILES += module.o
```

Assume `module.o` doesn't exist on disk (because I forgot to create it, or whatever).

Debate about why I don't just use `project.exe: module.o` aside (this is an MCVE! I do more things with `$OBJECT_FILES` elsewhere, in reality) how can I get a better diagnostic?

```
$ make all
make: *** No rule to make target `project.exe', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

I'd prefer:

```
$ make all
make: *** No rule to make target `module.o', needed by `project.exe'.  Stop.
```

Can Make be co-erced to do this without fundamentally changing my design?

Or, at least, why is it doing this?

---

```
$ make -v | head -n 2
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message make would have to display could become rather complicated. The reason for that is because of the implicit pattern rule, make is actually trying one after the other every rule whose target match `project.exe` and there could be an indefinite number. Consider for example the following:

```
OBJECT_FILES=

.PHONY: all
all: project.exe

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.exe:: $$(OBJECT_FILES);
%.exe:: does-not-exist-on-unix;
%.exe:: does-not-exist-on-amiga;
%.exe:: does-not-exist-except-perhaps-by-redmond;

project.exe: OBJECT_FILES += does-not-exist
```

Using `make` with the `-dr` options, this is what we get:

```
  Considering target file 'project.exe'.
   File 'project.exe' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'project.exe'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'project'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'does-not-exist'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'project'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'does-not-exist-on-unix'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'project'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'does-not-exist-on-amiga'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'project'.
   Trying rule prerequisite 'does-not-exist-except-perhaps-by-redmond'.
   No implicit rule found for 'project.exe'.
```

The line `Trying implicit prerequisite 'does-not-exist'` is the "best" way make tells you the prerequisite of the first pattern rule (the one with the secondary expansion of OBJECT_FILES) was attempted.

Also, if *any* of rules has its prerequisites found, then you won't get any error message: make simply allows implicit pattern rules to fail "silently", and it's actually happening a lot if you don't disable built-in rules. For example, built-in rules can produce an object file (.o target) out of several types of source files, like .cpp (C++), .c (C), .p (Pascal), .f (Fortran)... So depending on which source file is actually there, the right rule will be picked up, and the other rules will be silently "dropped". If you've got both a .c and a .cpp file, I don't know what happens!

If you can rewrite your makefile so that you don't have a pattern rule anymore, e.g. like this:

```
OBJECT_FILES=
EXE_FILES := project.exe project2.exe

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXE_FILES)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(EXE_FILES):: $$(OBJECT_FILES);

project.exe: OBJECT_FILES += does-not-exist
project2.exe: OBJECT_FILES += does-not-exist-either
```

Then make will output the messages you want (albeit not in the expected order):

`$ make -k all`

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'does-not-exist-either', needed by 'project2.exe'.
make: Target 'project2.exe' not remade because of errors.
make: *** No rule to make target 'does-not-exist', needed by 'project.exe'.
make: Target 'all' not remade because of errors.
```